# Perdendo dados ao comunicar com C#

Tags: c#, arduino, serial, porta-serial

Meu *Arduíno* envia dados continuamente para minha aplicação em *C#* via *porta Serial*. Porém, percebo que os primeiros valores enviados pelo *Arduíno* estão simplesmente sumindo, as vezes somem mais números, as vezes menos, e sempre somente no início da aplicação. Exemplo:

> Arduíno envia -> "0 1 100 1023 45 67 ..."
>
> C# recebe -> " 1023 45 67 ..." ou "1 100 1023 45 67..."

Atualmente estou **printando** na *Serial* da seguinte forma:

```
//ARDUINO:

int CANAL1, CANAL2, CANAL3;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    analogReference(DEFAULT);
    CANAL1 = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.print(CANAL1,DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    CANAL2 = analogRead(A1);  
    Serial.print(CANAL2,DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    CANAL3 = analogRead(A2);
    Serial.print(CANAL3,DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
}
```

E na minha aplicação em *C#*, a **recepção** dos dados é feita seguinte forma:

```
//C#

string RxString = "";

private void SerialCOM_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SerialCOM.IsOpen)
    {
        SerialPort sData = (SerialPort)sender;
        {
            RxString += sData.ReadExisting();
        }
    }
}
```

Esse tipo de problema não poderia acontecer em minha aplicação, pois desencadearia problemas com outras funções.

Tem algo de errado na recepção ou no envio das informações? Já fiz e refiz isso muitas vezes e todas acontece esse mesmo problema.

Comment: Como consegue comprovar _programaticamente_ que as mensagens enviadas e recebidas são exatamente essas?

Comment: Aterrei a entrada A0 do Arduíno no hardware e deixei um sinal conhecido em A1 e A2, fiz inspeção pelo Monitor Serial provando que o primeiro número correspondia a entrada A0, todas as vezes.

Comment: Perder informações em comunicação serial é normal. Sua aplicação deve ser robusta o suficiente para tentar sinalizar erros de comunicação, no protocolo de comunicação.

Comment: De qualquer forma, você pode tentar fazer handshaking em hardware https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.handshake?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Se é normal perder informações na comunicação, existe alguma maneira de saber qual a informação e a qual entrada do Arduino ela pertence pelo C#?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nessa Handshake, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Veja se o código abaixo funciona. No método você recebe os dados. Geralmente é assim que recebo dados do Arduino.

```
private List<byte> byte_buffer = new List<byte>();

private void SerialCOM_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {

byte_buffer.Clear();
while (SerialCOM.BytesToRead > 0) {
  byte_buffer.Add((byte)SerialCOM.ReadByte());
}
}
```

Os dados recebidos são adicionados a uma List. Se quiseres, podes usar **`byte_buffer.ToString()`** para imprimir a string recebida.

Peço perdão em caso de algum erro. Estou no celular, não tenho como testar até chegar em casa.